# What does "outstanding" mean in specific economic term?

Tags: word-meaning

When I read a [webpage](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/c/cashconversioncycle.asp), I saw the word "outstanding"

I am wondering what does "**Outstanding**" actually mean in these case on that webpage

Days of inventory **outstanding**

Days sales **outstanding**

Days payables **outstanding**

Comment: outstanding: not yet paid OR not yet settled or recorded in the accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not yet realized/finished in ordinary speech. Thus, as Lambie says, there are this many days of inventory 'yet to come'; there are this many days sales 'yet to be written down' (or perhaps, this many more days where there will be a sale); etc.
However this website is focused on accounting, so these terms are perverted into very specific uses. Thus, "Days inventory outstanding (DIO) is the average number of days that a company holds its inventory before selling it."
You would do well to Google each particular term and read a lot about the way it is used. It is NOT standard English.